# Use a texfile for the save data but it just blank when rewrite

Tags: python

So the level and the players score is saved in a textfile but now in order to rewrite the data so that when it loads again it is saved where the player is i use this code

```
#Exit button
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        Game_data = open('Gamedata.txt','w')
        Game_data.write(level)
        Game_data.write(str(Score))
        Game_data.close
        game_over = True
```

But now the texfile data just gets removed and stays empty

```
#Load in text file data
Game_data = open('Gamedata.txt','r')

level = Game_data.readline().split("\n")

Score = Game_data.readline().split("\n")
lives = Game_data.readline().split("\n")
```

this is the code to read the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have an issue with your string parsing, or perhaps not closing the file. I've created a minimal example that demonstrates loading and saving your game data to a file. Some minor event handling to change the values saved.

```
import pygame

def load_game_data():
    "Load save data, minimal error checking"
    try:
        with open("game_data.txt", "r") as save_file:
            level = save_file.readline().strip()  # remove newline
            score = int(save_file.readline())
            lives = int(save_file.readline())
        return level, score, lives
    except FileNotFoundError:  # no save file, return defaults
        return "First", 0, 0

def save_game_data(level, score, lives):
    "Save game data, no error checking"
    with open("game_data.txt", "w") as save_file:
        save_file.write(f"{level}\n")
        save_file.write(f"{score}\n")
        save_file.write(f"{lives}\n")

WIDTH = 640
HEIGHT = 480
FPS = 30

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
level, score, lives = load_game_data()

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            score += 1
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            lives += 1

    # draw surface - fill background
    window.fill(pygame.color.Color("grey"))
    # update window title to show score
    pygame.display.set_caption(f"Level: {level:10} Lives: {lives:5} Score: {score:5}")
    # show surface
    pygame.display.update()
    # limit frames
    clock.tick(FPS)
# frames += 1
pygame.quit()
save_game_data(level, score, lives)
```

I think format strings are clearer and more explicit. The only thing that tripped me up was stripping the newline when reading the level. The `int()` function ignores trailing newlines/spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you are not closing the file? you are not using the close method `close()`

Also as a general better practice you should use:

```
with open('Gamedata.txt','r') as file:
    file.write(level)
    file.write(str(Score))
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I missed the () by the .close and then i had to add the \n for the new line and it fixed the problem

```
Game_data = open('Gamedata.txt','w')
Game_data.write(f"{level}\n")
Game_data.write(str(f"{Score}\n"))
Game_data.write(str(f"{lives}\n"))
Game_data.close()
```